# Swift package created by SPM doesn't have access to full Foundation?

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I've created a library via `swift package init --type library` and I just noticed that not everything in Foundation is available, for example `NSAttributedString(data:options:documentAttributes:)` doesn't exist. How is that possible? Do I need to mark my package in some way that it runs on iOS and macOS or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `NSAttributedString`, the class itself, is available in Foundation. It should work in your swift package, too.

But, `NSAttributedString(data:options:documentAttributes:)` isn't. Why?

[image]

It seems like this is a convenience initializer that's part of UIKit.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that this was specifically part of UIKit.